# Groovy swap variables like ruby

Tags: groovy, swap

Which is the best way to swap to variable in Groovy?

Is it possibile to do something like in Ruby?

> x,y = y,x

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use parentheses for multiple assignment

```
(x,y) = [ y, x ]
```

Comment: Beauty! I needed this to swap 2 dates fromDate/toDate if toDate lies before fromDate.